# Fighting procrastination: how to disable wi-fi for a certain amount of hours without ability to reactivate until countdown ends

Tags: networking, 18.10

Is there a utility or command that I can use to disable my network connections for a set amount of hours, without having the ability to reverse this until said time has elapsed?

I'm on ubuntu 18.10

Comment: No: If you have the power to disable the connection at will, then you also have the power to reconnect at will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done without script. Edit crontab with `crontab -e` and put something like this(change hours to desired)

```
*/3 20-5 * * * /usr/bin/nmcli radio wifi off > /dev/null 2>&1
*/3 6-19 * * * /usr/bin/nmcli radio wifi on > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This will run command every 3 minutes, on specified hours. So, if you turn wifi on, it can switch off again in few minutes. As you are sudo user I can't find a way to make impossible to turn wifi back on. You can always edit crontab and enable "procrastination"

Answer (score 1):

U can do it easily using a script!!

Open mousepad/leafpad from the menu,
Type (or copy/paste)

```
#!bin/bash
nmcli radio wifi off
sleep $(( 60*60*8 ))
nmcli radio wifi on
```

This will put off wifi for *8* hours. (see above)
Now chmod this script,

```
chmod +x wifi_off
```

Replace wifi_off with the name of the file u saved.

Put it in a cronjob

```
crontab -e
```

Edit your cron file to look like this

```
50 20 * * * bash wifi_off
```

*This means it will set off this script at 8.50 pm and put off wifi for 8 hours.*

And save it!

Comment: I'm surprised that I can turn off wifi without sudo. Other problem: what happens if the system is shutdown during the n hours? The script will not get to turn wifi on until the system runs through from 8.50 pm to 4.50 am.

Comment: Its better to check time period in script and run it every few minutes. It will survive reboot and turning on wifi by user.

Comment: Thank you! I tried the script you provided (though I changed the third line to `sleep $(( 60*5 ))` to test it) and then executed it with `bash wifi_off`.. it works but I can turn the wifi back on from my network interface. I was looking for something that would make it impossible for me to turn wifi back on. In addition, even if setting a cronjob would solve the issue (I have not tried that) I would like to be able to execute the script whenever I want. @LeonidMew perhaps your suggestion addresses exactly this point, how could I do that?